# Validate Symfony 2 form with array and entity

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I'm building a form for array data that embeds an entity type like this:

```
$data = array('message' => '', 'book' => new Book());
$formBld = $this->createFormBuilder($data);
$formBld->add('book', new BookType(), array(
        'label' => false,
        'constraints' => new Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid()
     ))
     ->add('message', 'textarea')
     ->add('send', 'submit')
;
```

The `Book` entity contains validation constraints, but they are never called. What is missing/wrong?

Comment: Do you use validation groups for `Book` entity constraints?

Comment: That's it, @pazulx ! I had a validation group there. Can you write a short answer so I can choose that answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Valid` constraint do not support [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups). Only constraints without group will be used.

For example:

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        email:
            - Email: { groups: [registration] }
        password:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [registration] }
            - Length: { min: 7, groups: [registration] }
        city:
            - Length:
                min: 2
```

If you use `Valid` constraint on `UserType` then only the `city` `Length` will be validated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here, if you have added validation to the Book entity the form will automatically use these validations of the specified class.

For this to work you should pass the object Book to the form or use the data_class option in the BookType to set the Book entity.

To use the data_class option you would do the following:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'YourName\YourBundle\Entity\Book',
    ));
}
```

However you can specify different validations with the constraints key.

When you specified this Valid class constraint you override the constraints which are defined in the Book entity.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-option-constraints

Comment: Thanks! While this did not solve my problem in this case (I already had the correct `data_class` in my default options, my error was caused by wrong validation groups in the form initialization), it's generally a good approach to do it like you do.